# How to generate normals for VBO?

Tags: opengl, vbo, normals

I've implemented a wavefront (OBJ) file loader for my OpenGL app which provides me face, texture and vertex information. However, to use lighting I obviously need normal information. I know the correct way to do this is to take the cross product of the 3 vertices that comprise a triangle and normalise. This results in a normal that you apply to all 3 vertices correct?

However, for faces/triangles that are not on the edge of the polygon, each vertex is used 3 times. So I'm guessing you just average each newly calculated normal with the previously calculated normals?

This seems like it is a hugely expensive task the way I'm thinking of doing it; iterating through all the vertices and calculating the normals for each face that use that vertex and averaging. Is there a better/quicker way to do this?

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, averaging the per-face normals of the faces adjacent to a vertex gives good results. To keep very hard edges 'hard', you'd typically introduce an angle limit into the calculation to keep >90 (or even lower angles) degree edges from receiving averaged normals.

A OSS project I'm involved with has a [freely available implementation](http://assimp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/assimp/trunk/code/GenVertexNormalsProcess.cpp?revision=661&view=markup) of this algorithm. It is `O(nlogn)` and operates on totally unique vertices (each face references 3 vertices, but each vertex is referenced by only one face - joining equal vertices together is done at a later stage).

If you have totally distinct vertices (i.e. each vertex position exists only once), it can be done in `O(n)` time, but limiting the edge angle for smoothing is more difficult to implement then.

Comment: Thanks for that! That was how I was thinking of doing it. Glad to get a little reassurance that it was a correct way!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here [OBJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) supports definitions of normals. Why not let the 3D program do the hard work? :)

Comment: The application receives models from all over the place (different vendors etc) so I cannot always guarantee that normals will be declared, particularly if the model just contains geometry information. I have a few models for testing that include normal data and it does indeed make life a hell of a lot easier) :p. For those models that don't, I can't for the life of me figure out how to make Cinema4d generate normals either :o

Comment: @Chris Robinson: Ok... Bit cheeky of Cinema 4D to omit it considering it must have the info readily available.

Comment: I'm sure it has it available, I just don't have the time to sift through menu's to find it :p It is a bit annoying that they don't make it trivial though.

Comment: @Chris Robinson: It's worth noting that a modeler-generated normal will always have higher quality than reconstructed ones. Reason is, the artist made sure it looked good with the lighting in the modeler.